# Typed SRV always fetches zero

Tags: directx-12, direct3d12

The vertex shader always receives zero when looking up a typed resource view.

```
Buffer<unorm float> UnormBuffer : register(t0);

float4 main(VSInput input, uint id : SV_VertexID) : SV_POSITION
{
    float mag = 100.f * UnormBuffer[id];
    // mag always zero
}
```

The shader resource view bound to `t0` has type `DXGI_FORMAT_R8_UNORM`.

The draw call is using instancing.

The debug layer doesn't emit any warnings or errors.

PIX shows the SRV to have the correct data, but when I step through the shader, zero is always returned.

Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SRV was wasn't actually typed DXGI_FORMAT_R8_UNORM, but was actually a structured buffer with stride `1`. Correcting that fixed the problem.